# I have TOR installed but cannot open onion websites. Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.10, tor

I can run the tor browser bundle and it works fine for opening regular websites, but whenever I try to open onion websites, they just time-out. I am running the 32-bit version of Ubuntu, and I don't know much about Linux in general, other than how to navigate the folders with commands, such as ls, cd, rm and the like.

Comment: Have you tried the same website in a different operating system and/or on a different computer with Ubuntu and Tor? It seems more likely the issue is with the website itself or with your version of Tor rather than with Ubuntu, given that other websites work fine.

Comment: I dont have any other computers that run ubuntu.